# Cierre inesperado de sesiones en IIS

Tags: iis

Actualmente tengo un problema con mi IIS y es que algunos usuarios me han reportado que se les cierra su sesión de manera
inesperada en la aplicación web, incluso antes del timeout configurado que es de 15 minutos.
La aplicación que corre esta sobre .net framework 4.6 y la base de datos es sql server 2016.
Ya he revisado el rendimiento del servidor web y base de datos pero no se ve saturación de consumo de RAM o CPU ni tampoco
he visto errores en el event viewer del web server. El reciclyng esta configurado para realizarse diariamente a las 3:00 am.
Algo que me puedan sugerir validar ya sea en el los servidores o en los clientes?

Comment: Hola Fabian, esto es SOes, el único idioma aceptado es el español, por favor, podrías editar tu pregunta y traducirla?, y si tienes un error, agregar el código y los mensajes recibidos como texto. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Gracias, no habia caido en cuenta. Ya la dejé en español.